# How do I send multiple http requests with rx.js?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I am trying out `rx.js` and I am trying to make multiple `http` request.  Here is the `observable` that I have set up to make the `http` request.

```
function httpGet(url) {
    return Observable.create(function forEach(observer) {
        var cancelled = false;
        axios.get(url).then(function(res) {
            if(!cancelled) {
                observer.onNext(res);
                observer.onCompleted();             
            }
        });

        return function dispose() {
            cancelled = true;
        }
    })
}
```

I am trying to make multiple `http` requests, but my result is more `Observable`'s.  Here is the `subscribe`:

```
var array = ['http://localhost:4444/text/88', 'http://localhost:4444/other/77'];

var source = Rx.Observable.fromArray(array).map(httpGet);

var subscription = source.subscribe(
    function (x) {
        console.log(x);
    },
    function (err) {
        console.log('Error: ' + err);
    },
    function () {
        console.log('Completed');
});
```

And here is my result.

```
AnonymousObservable { source: undefined, __subscribe: [Function: forEach] }
AnonymousObservable { source: undefined, __subscribe: [Function: forEach] }
Completed
```

I understand that I am getting `Observable`'s and if I `forEach`ed through them, then I would get the result, but I am missing the proper way of transforming this into `data` and not an `Observable`.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That should do the trick:

```
var array = ['http://localhost:4444/text/88', 'http://localhost:4444/other/77'];

var source = Rx.Observable.fromArray(array).concatMap(httpGet);

function httpGet(url) {
  return axios.get(url);
  }
var subscription = source.subscribe(
    function (x) {
        console.log(x);
    },
    function (err) {
        console.log('Error: ' + err);
    },
    function () {
        console.log('Completed');
});
```

Some explanations:

- an observable is a sequence of values. An observer is a three-pronged object which processes those values.
- what you want is turn the array (source) into a sequence of html (obtained from fetching the urls). What you have at your disposal is :

  - a set of functions for creating observables from external sources : cf. https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/gettingstarted/categories.md, section `Converting events or asynchronous patterns to observable sequences, or between Arrays and observable sequences.`
  - a set of operators allowing to take those source sequences into the sequences of your making (same link than above).
- you then want to subscribe to the produced sequences and do something with them. That is the `subscribe` function where you define your observer.
- so here you take your sequence of array values, produce a sequence of promises with the `map` operator, BUT actually you will use the `concatMap` operator to output the promise resolved values in the same order than the array values. `concatMap` can take an observable, an array/iterable or a promise as its argument, and will output the sequence of values wrapped into those objects in the observable it returns. So instead of having a sequence of promises you have a sequence of values resolved by the promises i.e. your fetched html content. If you are not interested in keeping the initial ordering of the source, you could also use the `flatMap` operator. Cf. https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/concatmap.md and https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/selectmany.md
- then you subscribe to that, and process those values

So this is basically the general process, you take a source sequence, turn that into a sequence of your choice through a judicious choice of operators, and then process the values one by one with your observer function.
Also, note that a promise is akin to an observable, and some (most?) `Rxjs` operators will treat them as such, so you often do not have to use `then` to get the resolved value.

Last thing, `Rx.Observable.fromArray` seems to be deprecated in favor of `Rx.Observable.from` : cf. https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/fromarray.md

Comment: I think it's worth to mention that `concatMap` executes the requests one by one, in order, which may be inefficient in some cases. Consider using `forkJoin` or `combineLatest` for parallel requests. Moreover, you can use them and pipe a `timeout` with `catchError` to prevent lengthy requests.

Comment: that is a fair observation. Feel free to edit the post or add your own answer, I'll upvote it